# Throttling with PNP Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, throttling

I try to run a script with PNP PowerShell, clearing file versions on SharePoint that exceeds 10.
It works fine on smaller sites, but when I try running it on larger sites with thousands of files, I get 503 as a return error, indicating that I am being hard throttled.

As I read it, throttling should be handled in PNP PowerShell. I never see the soft throttling errors, only the hard throttling.

I understand that I can somehow retrieve the retry-after headers of the HTTP request, then maybe set a sleep timer according to the header value, (I haven't figured out how to retrieve it yet).

Sometimes the connection is forcefully closed when running Get-PnPList, other times it's stopped when running ¤Ctx.Load($File).

I hope you guys can help.

```
Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
    #Get the Context
    $Ctx= Get-PnPContext
 
    #Exclude certain libraries
    $ExcludedLists = @("Form Templates", "Preservation Hold Library","Site Assets", "Pages", "Site Pages", "Images",
                            "Site Collection Documents", "Site Collection Images","Style Library")
 
    #Get All document libraries
    $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -notin $ExcludedLists -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}
 
    #Iterate through each document library
    ForEach($Library in $DocumentLibraries)
    {
        Write-host "Processing Document Library:"$Library.Title -f Magenta
 
        #Get All Items from the List - Exclude 'Folder' List Items
        $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Library -PageSize 5000 | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
 
        #Loop through each file
        ForEach ($Item in $ListItems)
        {
            #Get File Versions
            $File = $Item.File
            $Versions = $File.Versions
            $Ctx.Load($File)
            $Ctx.Load($Versions)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
            Write-host -f Yellow "`tScanning File:"$File.Name
            $VersionsCount = $Versions.Count
            $VersionsToDelete = $VersionsCount - $VersionsToKeep
            If($VersionsToDelete -gt 0)
            {
                write-host -f Cyan "`t Total Number of Versions of the File:" $VersionsCount
                $VersionCounter= 0
                #Delete versions
                For($i=0; $i -lt $VersionsToDelete; $i++)
                {
                    If($Versions[$VersionCounter].IsCurrentVersion)
                    {
                       $VersionCounter++
                       Write-host -f Magenta "`t`t Retaining Current Major Version:"$Versions[$VersionCounter].VersionLabel
                       Continue
                    }
                    Write-host -f Cyan "`t Deleting Version:" $Versions[$VersionCounter].VersionLabel
                    $Versions[$VersionCounter].DeleteObject()
                }
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                Write-Host -f Green "`t Version History is cleaned for the File:"$File.Name
            }
        }Write-Host "Finished Cleaning " + $SiteURL
    }
}

Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Cleaning up Version History!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug accord to following : https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/3473   The last posting asks if anybody has a fix in early October.  Looks like there may be a solution here which is posted later in October : https://kinsta.com/blog/http-error-503/

Comment: Thank you, but I already saw that thread, but there's no solution.
The blog you posted is for WordPress.

Comment: Why would the solution be different just for Word Press?  Word Press is just a different backend database.

Comment: because the API and throttle limits are different and I am using a module specific for sharepoint

Comment: Wouldn't the steps to tune your system be the same as the Word Press solution?  Just the limits may need to be changed.